# Не работает команда pyautogui.typewrite на языках

Tags: python

написал простейший код какой только может быть для команды pyautogui.typewrite но всё равно он не хочет её писать. Код пишет только цифры, а английские или русские буквы писать не хочет.Помогите пожалуйста что с этим делать?

```
from time import sleep
import pyautogui
sleep(3)
pyautogui.typewrite("Hello123")
```

В итоге код смог написать только : 123

Answer (score 0):

Это у меня сработало:

```
pyautogui.write('Hello world!123')
```